# replacing the missing value with different values on the same column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
     A      B     C   D
1  2010    one    0   0
2  2020    one    2   4
3  2007    two    0   8
4  2010    one    8   4
5  2020    four   6  12
6  2007    three  0  14
7  2006    four   7  14
8  2010    two    10 12
```

I need to replace 0 with the average of the C values of years.For example 2010 C value would be 9. What is the best way to do this? i have over 10,000 rows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free coding service. Provide a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` to change 0's to `np.nan` in Column C, and use `fillna` to `map` the yearly averages:

```
df.C.replace({0:np.nan},inplace=True)

df.C.fillna(
    df.A.map(
        df.groupby(df['A']).\
            C.mean().fillna(0)\
            .to_dict()
        ),inplace=True
    )

print(df)

      A      B     C   D
0  2010    one   9.0   0
1  2020    one   2.0   4
2  2007    two   0.0   8
3  2010    one   8.0   4
4  2020   four   6.0  12
5  2007  three   0.0  14
6  2006   four   7.0  14
7  2010    two  10.0  12
```

2007 is still `NaN` because we have no values other than 0's in the initial data.

Comment: Congratulations for reaching 10k, @sophocles!! :D

Comment: Thank you @richardec! And to you too :) happy new year

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I think I will do it. The code below will be pseudo-code.

1: You find the avg for each year, and put it to a dict.

```
my_year_dict = {'2020':xxx,'2021':xxx}
```

2: Use apply & lambda functions

```
df[New C Col] = df[C].apply(lambda x: my_year_dict[x] if x is 0)
```

Hope it can be a start!

Comment: But as i said in my question i have 10,00 rows so it is really hard for me to put every avg value to a dict